# Has Firebase FCM a subscribers limit? TOO_MANY_SUBSCRIBERS error

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

recently I started getting this type of error in production when registering to some topics:

```
Invalid registration response :'Error=TOO_MANY_SUBSCRIBERS'. It is missing 'token' field.
```

I'm using the following method on iOS Platform to register the device to a topic:

```
Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: String, completion: ((Error?) -> Void))
```

Environment:

```
  - FirebaseMessaging (7.0.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 7.0)
    - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 7.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 7.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Reachability (~> 7.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (~> 7.0)
```

The error suggests that firebase has a limit on the number of subscriptions to the topic, is this?

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging), FCM has no total topic subscriptions limit, but a 2000 subscriptions per app instance limit.

> Topic messaging supports unlimited subscriptions for each topic.
> However, FCM enforces limits in these areas:
>
> - One app instance can be subscribed to no more than 2000 topics.
> - If you are using batch import to subscribe app instances, each    request is limited to 1000 app instances.
> - The frequency of new subscriptions is rate-limited per project. If    you send too many subscription requests in a short period of time,
>   FCM servers will respond with a 429 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED ("quota
>   exceeded") response. Retry with exponential backoff.

Comment: Thank you Fabio, but this answer doesn't help me a lot, I don't think that is the 2000 subscriptions limit

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit on subscribers per topic, as well there is no limit on number of created topics per project.

There is a limit how fast client apps can be subscribed or unsubscribed from a topic - [3000 queries per second](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#topics_throttling).

It looks like too many users are trying to subscribe to the topic, implement a retry logic.